# Draw a Square Without a Compass, Only a Straightedge

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I remember seeing the following question in an old [STEP](https://www.admissionstesting.org/for-test-takers/step/about-step/) question:

> using only a straight-edge and a set of (unmarked) coordinate axes, construct a square.

I'm sure I knew how to do it when I was preparing for STEP, but I don't remember now. I also can't find the STEP question, otherwise there would likely be a solution for it on The Student Room. I just remember it being pretty cool!

---

**Update.**
So it seems that this problem is not solvable (and hence I misremembered the question). Having given it some further thought, I think I have remembered the question correctly now; I have reposted it at [Draw a Square Without a Compass, Only a Straightedge -- Part Deux](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941109/draw-a-square-without-a-compass-only-a-straightedge-part-deux). (I thought it seemed too large a change to be ok as an edit, as all the comments and answers would no longer be relevant.)

Comment: Are the coordinate axes marked or not?

Comment: Sorry, unmarked, as otherwise it's trivial

Answer (score 4):

Not that I've proved it, but I suspect this is impossible.

That's assuming that "using a straightedge" means exactly what it means in traditional Euclidean constructions.

Just to inject a minimal amount of content, I also have a conjecture how this is consistent with the fact that the OP says he saw a solution once. I conjecture that that solution cheated. For example, it's easy to construct a square if we're given an actual physical ruler and we're allowed to use the fact that the two edges are parallel.

And a vague notion of where a proof of impossibility might come from: The constructions we can make with a straightedge, starting with those two axes, are invariant under the transformation $(x,y)\mapsto(2x,y)$.

Comment: I think your 'vague notion' does give a rigorous proof. The stretch-transform preserves the two axes and all lines constructed, so any purported square construction must also succeed under the stretch, but obviously it fails.

Comment: The question I saw was a STEP question, which is used for entrance exams to Cambridge undergraduate tripos, so it's extremely unlikely to be false; also, the solution that I saw didn't use anything like "parallel edges of a physical ruler". That said, **the question I saw...**. I saw this around May 2012, which is a dishearteningly long time ago, so it seems that I have misremembered.

Comment: I have just posted what I think is the correct version of this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941109/draw-a-square-without-a-compass-only-a-straightedge-part-deux)

Answer (score 1):

How about joining $\left(1,0\right)$ to $\left(0,1\right)$ to $\left(-1,0\right)$ to $\left(0,-1\right)$ back to $\left(1,0\right)$ by straight lines?

Comment: Nice. I suspect it's impossible to construct a _unit_ square, since that would require constructing $\sqrt{2}$ without a compass.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said explicitly: unmarked coordinate axes. Basically just two (doubly-infinite) lines perpendicular to each other.

Comment: @EthanBolker is it not possible to construct $\sqrt 2$ without a compass?

Comment: Note that we already have a set of perpendicular lines, so it's not like we're starting from nothing

Comment: @samStreeter The OP has edited the question to say the axes are unmarked, so this nice solution isn't one.

Comment: Okay... I'm fairly new here, so am I supposed to delete this after his revision? I don't think the revised problem is solvable.

Comment: I didn't actually say originally that they were marked -- are coordinate axes normally? I didn't think so, but maybe I'm the unusual one! That said, it appears that with the original interpretation it isn't solvable. (This is possibly why you added "marked", as otherwise there is no solution!)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, though. I have just posed the hopefully correct version of this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941109/draw-a-square-without-a-compass-only-a-straightedge-part-deux); if you have any insights for it, they'd be most welcome there! :)

Comment: @SamT I wouldn't call them coordinate axes if they were unmarked, as then there are no coordinates to speak of. I would rather say two (doubly) infinite perpendicular lines, but that is just my perception of the terminology, and of course it doesn't matter now that you have clarified the question. Thank you for your nice response, and sorry for misunderstanding. I have also taken a look at your new question, and it's a very nice problem with a beautiful solution!

Comment: @SamStreeter I guess you're right: if you can't use the axes to put any coordinates down (for which one needs markings), then I shouldn't really call them "*coordinate* axes"!